# Setting values on form submission using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm using the following code to geocode a supplied address using the Google Maps API.  The idea is to geocode the address and pass the lat/long in the form post so that my controller action can utilize it.  Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work as the lat/long aren't submitted with the rest of the form.  What am I doing wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#search_form").submit(function(event) {
        var address = $("#searchAddress").val();

        if (address != "") {
            var geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();

            geocoder.getLatLng(
                address,
                function(point) {
                    if (point) {
                        // Found address, populate hidden form fields
                        $("#searchLatitude").val(point.lat());
                        $("#searchLongitude").val(point.lng());  
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

geocoder.getLatLong() is asynchronous so your Submit is not waiting on your function(point) to be called.

Add a button (not a submit of course) and attach a click handler like so:

```
$("#buttonId").click(function() {

    var address = $("#searchAddress").val();

        if (address != "") {
            var geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();

            geocoder.getLatLng(
                address,
                function(point) {
                    if (point) {
                        // Found address, populate hidden form fields
                        $("#searchLatitude").val(point.lat());
                        $("#searchLongitude").val(point.lng());  

                        $("#search_form").submit();

                    }
                }
            );
        }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are submitting the form and then setting the values. This does not work. You need to set the values and then submit the form.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.  Is there a standard workaround to this?

Comment: There are some good suggestions in the other answers. You could look into them.

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery form plug-in](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) will make your life easier. There is a beforeSubmit event that you could use.